# Unable to read/import Windows XML log file using Import-Clixml or Get-Content

Tags: xml, powershell

Windows creates a nice XML log file in `$ENV:windir\System32\WDI\LogFiles\StartupInfo\` that tells you about start-up apps/processes, their CPU usage, disk usage and load time.

I have spent a while trying to load and read this file in PowerShell with the goal of manipulating the data as a PSObject or Hashtable.

When I using `Import-clixml` I get the following error:

```
PS C:\Users> $data = Import-Clixml -Path "C:\Windows\System32\WDI\LogFiles\StartupInfo\StartupInfo1.xml"
Import-Clixml : Element 'Objs' with namespace name 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04' was not found. Line 2, position 2.
At line:1 char:9
+ $data = Import-Clixml -Path "C:\Windows\System32\WDI\LogFiles\Startup ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Import-Clixml], XmlException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Xml.XmlException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportClixmlCommand
```

and when I attempt the collection using `[xml]$Data = Get-Content...` it works, but doesn't provide the structure I'd expect:

```
    PS C:\Users> [xml]$data = Get-Content -Path "C:\Windows\System32\WDI\LogFiles\StartupInfo\StartupInfo1.xml"

    PS C:\Users> $data

    xml                             StartupData
    ---                             -----------
    version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" StartupData



    PS C:\Users\alt63> $data.StartupData

    IntervalStartMs IntervalEndMs ReadAheadAnalysisTime RurLegacyResourceAttribution
    --------------- ------------- --------------------- ----------------------------
    138080          228080        0                     0
```

The XML content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<StartupData IntervalStartMs="15383" IntervalEndMs="105383">
    <Process Name="C:\Devi" PID="8928" StartedInTraceSec="33.422">
        <StartTime>2019/02/19:00:01:48.6792251</StartTime>
        <CommandLine><![CDATA["C:\Users\user_a\AppData\Local\slack\Update.exe" --processStart "slack.exe" --process-start-args "--startup"]]></CommandLine>
        <DiskUsage Units="bytes">9797632</DiskUsage>
        <CpuUsage Units="us">520359</CpuUsage>
        <ParentPID>5132</ParentPID>
        <ParentStartTime>2019/02/19:00:01:31.1627452</ParentStartTime>
        <ParentName>explorer.exe</ParentName>
    </Process>
    <Process Name="C:\Devic" PID="9064" StartedInTraceSec="34.440">
        <StartTime>2019/02/19:00:01:49.6967953</StartTime>
        <CommandLine>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"</CommandLine>
        <DiskUsage Units="bytes">11264</DiskUsage>
        <CpuUsage Units="us">40602</CpuUsage>
        <ParentPID>9012</ParentPID>
        <ParentStartTime>2019/02/19:00:01:49.4645583</ParentStartTime>
        <ParentName>chrome.exe</ParentName>
    </Process>
    <ReadAheadAnalysisTime>0</ReadAheadAnalysisTime>
    <RurLegacyResourceAttribution>31</RurLegacyResourceAttribution>
</StartupData>
```

(The log is a lot longer, data omitted for brevity)

Two queries:

1. What makes this XML different to any other XML file I'm using successfully.
2. Any thoughts on how best to tackle this file?

Thanks!

Comment: What output do you expect from structured xml data? Try `$data.StartupData.Process | Format-List *`

Comment: `Import-CliXml` is a serialization cmdlet meant to be used in tandem with `Export-CliXml`.  You should probably use `[xml](Get-Content ...)`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I've tried that (as shown in the question), but thanks!

Comment: @LotPings I get the same output as `Get-Content` above, but in list format. There are no hidden properties.

Comment: Do your tags have something that resembles `<ns:tagname` ?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 which tags are you referring to sorry? The XML example in the question shows all of the data I have available to work with (it's a log file generated by Windows during start-up). I might be misunderstanding your question?